# Gradle with QueryDSL 4.1.4 & Intellij

Tags: spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea, gradle, querydsl

I am trying to get my Q Classes for queryDSL 1.4.1 recongised in a Spring-Boot 1.5.2 project. The IDE is Intellij Ultimate.

**build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
ext {
    springBootVersion = '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    }
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'net.ltgt.apt' version '0.8'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'idea'

version = '0.0.5-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

ext {
    queryDslVersion = '4.1.4'
    javaGeneratedSources = file("$buildDir/generated-sources/java")
}

compileJava {
    doFirst {
        javaGeneratedSources.mkdirs()
    }
    options.compilerArgs += [
            '-parameters', '-s', javaGeneratedSources
    ]
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('generated/')
        generatedSourceDirs += file('generated/')
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-jdbc')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security')
    compile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail:1.5.7.RELEASE')
    compile ("org.thymeleaf.extras:thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4:3.0.0.RELEASE")
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-logging', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.thymeleaf.extras', name: 'thymeleaf-extras-springsecurity4', version: '2.1.2.RELEASE'
    compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-autoconfigure', version: '1.5.2.RELEASE'
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:2.4.0")

    compile group: 'org.hibernate', name: 'hibernate-java8'

    compile "com.querydsl:querydsl-root:$queryDslVersion"
    compile "com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:$queryDslVersion"
    compileOnly "com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:$queryDslVersion:jpa"

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools")
    compile('mysql:mysql-connector-java')
    testCompile('org.hsqldb:hsqldb')
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')
 }
```

The Q classes are generated at:

```
build\generated\source\apt\main\generated\com\example\domain
```

Even though the javaGeneratedSources points to file $buildDir/generated-sources/java (that folder is empty).

[image]

The build error is:

`C:\Users\User\IdeaProjects\demo3\src\main\java\com\example\services\EpServiceImpl.java:13: error: cannot find symbol
import com.example.domain.QEp;
                        ^
  symbol:   class QEp
  location: package com.example.domain`

I check other Stack Overflow answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38353062/intellij-15-with-querydsl-and-gradle?rq=1) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22773639/querydsl-spring-boot-gradle) but I have not been able to get these methods to work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I recommend trying this.

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        querydslVersion    = "4.1.4"
        metaModelsSourcesDir = file("metamodels")   
    }
}

configurations {
    querydslapt
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        java {
            srcDir metaModelsSourcesDir
        }
    }
}


task querymodels(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build') {
    doFirst {
        delete metaModelsSourcesDir;
        metaModelsSourcesDir.mkdirs();
    }

    classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.querydslapt
    destinationDir = metaModelsSourcesDir

    source = sourceSets.main.java
    options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-processor", "com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor",
            "-s", metaModelsSourcesDir
    ]
}

dependencies {
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:${querydslVersion}")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${querydslVersion}")

    querydslapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${querydslVersion}")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your Gradle is above 5, it won't work. 
https://github.com/ewerk/gradle-plugins/issues/116